# Spring cloud stream kafka consumer that bind to multiple topics

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to configure one consumer application (will run on one JVM) that will bind to multiple topics.
Each "consume" (let say I have 2 topics to listen) method in the consumer application will be set with @StreamListener annotation and will be linked to specific topic.
Also i will configure each consumer in a different consumer-group.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<consumer>.group=<group name>
```

The idea is to consume messages from few topics, lets assume all with the same priority, manipulate them and pass them to the relevant microServices.

How the consumer application will behave in such configuration?
The message will came one by one?
I need to implement each listner in a different thread?
Is this approach is good at all?

Kafka version 0.8.2.1 (spotify image)
Spring-cloud-stram Brixton.RELEASE
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the multiple topics, but I'm pretty certain the Kafka consumer cannot be in multiple groups at the same time.

Comment: I want to set each Kafka consumer to different consumer-group. e.g: topic "sync_message" wil be set with `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sync_message.group=sync_group` and topic "update_db" will be set with `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.update_db.group=db_group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How the consumer application will behave in such configuration?
>   The message will came one by one?
>   I need to implement each listner in a different thread?

In Brixton release, each @StreamListener methods will consume messages from separate threads (You will see the threads: FetchTask from KafkaMessageListenerContainer for each binding). Hence the message consumption is between these threads that correspond to consuming messages from respective topics.

Comment: So threads FetchTask(Kafka-fetch) will be created for each @Input annotation?

Comment: Yes, It is for each consumer binding.

Comment: BTW there is a recommended limit for bindings per application?

Comment: I think it depends on the requirement. If you can handle message rate using the multiple threads inside the same application, then you can include as many bindings inside the same application.